# Product failed under warranty. What can I do if the company ignores me

Tags: warranties

I purchased a product for about $80 which was advertised with a 5 year warranty. I am now in the 4th year of that warranty period and the device has stopped working.

I have emailed the company several times. I finally had a reply asking which product I purchased. I had already clearly stated this, but responded with the details again.

I haven't had a reply in over a month, and have sent weekly emails following it up.

What steps should I take next?

Comment: I would look to see if they have a presence on social media sites, and if they do, make a stink there. Companies tend to respond quickly to posts that make them look bad on facebook, twitter, etc. because unlike your emails, those things are public.

Comment: @CareyGregory That's the only reason I go on twitter :) Works a treat most of the time. What country is this anyway? If it's the UK there is [consumer law](https://www.which.co.uk/consumer-rights/advice/my-warranty-provider-wont-honour-the-warranty-what-can-i-do) to help you if the [company refuses to help](https://www.which.co.uk/consumer-rights/advice/what-to-do-if-your-extended-warranty-provider-refuses-your-claim)

Comment: Unfortunately they are a small company and their social media accounts aren't that big. They haven't posted very much over the last year so I doubt they would see any comments I made. Worth a try though.
It's a US company, but they do have a branch in the EU.

Comment: I heard back from them today. Their response was: "unfortunately the product is no longer supported, there are no more of these units in our warehouse"

Not even an apology. Am I missing something here?  Aren't they required by law to repair or provide me with a partial refund?

Comment: I am now sending them 2 emails a day. They have taken their support system offline.